# Does the Shapes have click event and Children in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wpf-controls

I am creating a Mancala Game. I have a canvas in the grid, inside the canvas I have circles that represent holes and Rectangles that represent Mancalas, and I also I have images that represent stones. I have used the Image control to get the Images.

The Images are in the circles. they have ZIndex -2 so they are under the circles to be correct, and the circles are transparent so you can see through.

I want to make the circles somehow clickable (I know there is no click event in shapes, but at another event which kinda resembles click would be enough). and then the Images underneath that circle will move to different coordinates on the canvas underneath next circles to be precise.

So my question is: is there any way to give circles children so I can know how many images are in that specific circle at a specific time?. Any additional advice will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are two solutions that come to my mind - either wrap the shape you want to make interactive in a UserControl and handle the click there or use DrawingVisuals instead of shapes, which support hit testing

Comment: Hello Nasir, you can use the "MouseUp" event it's the same as "Click" as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Shape doesn't have a `Click` event but you could handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

And it doesn't have a `Children` property either but you could probably solve your issue by adding the `Shape` and its "child" elements to the same `Grid`, e.g.:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" />
    <Image ... />
</Grid>
```

---

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Grid clickedGrid = (Grid)sender;
    Ellipse ellipse = clickedGrid.Children[0] as Ellipse;
    //...
}
```